# How to show own image as marker on google map ? gmaps4rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

gmaps4rails 2 + rails 4

```
def CommonUtils.get_gmap_hash(object)
     Gmaps4rails.build_markers(object) do |user, marker|
         marker.lat user.latitude
         marker.lng user.longitude
         marker.infowindow user.location
         binding.pry
         marker.picture({
            :picture => "/img/blank.png",
            :width   => 32,
            :height  => 32
            })
         marker.json({:title => user.title})
      end
  end
```

here marker.picture method is not hitting itself don't know why ? Any help ?

and default marker is coming i want different marker(blank.png).

blank.png is in assets/images/img/blank.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According [to the source](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/lib/gmaps4rails/markers_builder.rb#L16-L20), do:

```
 Gmaps4rails.build_markers(object) do |user, marker|
     marker.lat user.latitude
     marker.lng user.longitude
     marker.infowindow user.location
     marker.picture({
        :url     => "/img/blank.png",
        :width   => 32,
        :height  => 32
        })
     marker.json({:title => user.title})
  end
```